# How to Map Two Different Arrays in One Statement

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have no idea how to phrase this question. I would appreciate it if you could include a better way to phrase this in your answer. My question is; is there a way to write the following code in a single statement? The only real difference is one adds to featured projects if `e.featured` is false. And the other adds to openSourceProjects if it is true. I feel like I am missing something obvious.

```
  const featuredProjects = allProjects.map((e) => {
    if (e.featured == true) {
      return (
        buildCard(e)
      );
    }
  });

  const openSourceProjects = allProjects.map((e) => {
    if (e.featured == false) {
      return (
        buildCard(e)
      );
    }
  });
```

This seems dirty and is bordering on code duplication which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Your `map` callback isn't returning anything anyway, so there's nothing of value to assign to the variables…!?

Comment: also how did you do the `const allProjects = allProjects...`

Comment: @cmgchess sorry I shouldve tested that before posting. Ive edited back to the way I had it. I was just experimenting with some stuff.

Comment: you can do this in a single reduce to filter separately. let me see

Comment: `.map()` iterates over every element in an array and maps each element to a new value depending on what the callback returns. The resulting array is _always_ the same size as the original array. Your map functions here wont remove any elements. The elements that don't satisfy the if-statements wont return any value, so these will implicitly become `undefined` in the resulting array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can filter out the seperated in one reduce call. here is an example. you can push the `buildCard(curr)`

```js
const allProjects = [
  { title: "Project 1", featured: true },
  { title: "Project 2", featured: false },
  { title: "Project 3", featured: true },
  { title: "Project 4", featured: false },
  { title: "Project 5", featured: true },
  { title: "Project 6", featured: false },
];

const {featuredProjects, openSourceProjects} =  allProjects.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  acc[curr.featured ? 'featuredProjects': 'openSourceProjects'].push(curr)
  return acc
},{featuredProjects:[],openSourceProjects:[]})

console.log(featuredProjects)
console.log(openSourceProjects)
```

can even use an array as the accumulator. more readable as deceze
♦ mentioned

```js
const allProjects = [
  { title: "Project 1", featured: true },
  { title: "Project 2", featured: false },
  { title: "Project 3", featured: true },
  { title: "Project 4", featured: false },
  { title: "Project 5", featured: true },
  { title: "Project 6", featured: false },
];

const [featuredProjects, openSourceProjects] =  allProjects.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  acc[curr.featured ? 0 : 1].push(curr)
  return acc
},[[],[]])

console.log(featuredProjects)
console.log(openSourceProjects)
```

Comment: You could reduce the verboseness by using a simple array instead of an object with named properties for `acc`…

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the answer. Its almost about juggling between less verbose and more readable it seems like. Took me a second to realize what this does.

Comment: @zbarnz its something like conditionally putting into separate buckets based on the featured field. you can achieve this by doing `allProjects.filter` twice with opposite conditions but here it is just 1 loop instead of 2 loops with filter

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple utility function to help you avoid the duplication:

```
type Projects =  typeof allProjects;
const filter = (projects: Projects, featured: boolean) =>
  projects.filter(p => p.featured === featured).map(buildCard);
```

and use it like this:

```
const featuredProjects = filter(allProjects, true);
const openSourceProjects = filter(allProjects, false);
```

Now it's simple and readable.

(Note: The `Projects` type you would probably define more explicitly in real code, but not knowing the type I used the `typeof` operator to make it work in this example.)